# Metabox - Displaying the Value of a Metabox

Tags: php, metabox

newbie here.

I am struggling around for hours. I am developing my first WP Plugin where 
I can enter products (product title and description). 
It seems that wp saves my description in the db, because if I open the product in the backend I can see my saved description. But if I'm trying to echo the description I get an empty value.

Below are some code-snippets:

metabox:

```
function product_custom_meta(){
    add_meta_box('product_meta', __('Product Title', 'product-textdomain' ), 'product_meta_callback', 'url' );
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'product_custom_meta');

function product_meta_callback( $post ) {
    wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'product_nonce' );
    $product_stored_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID );
    ?>

    <p>
        <label for="meta-desc" class="product-row-title"><?php _e( 'Description', 'product-textdomain' )?></label>
        <input type="text" name="meta_desc" id="meta_desc" value="<?php if ( isset ( $product_stored_meta['meta-desc'] ) ) echo $product_stored_meta['meta-desc'][0]; ?>" />
    </p>


    <?php
}

function product_meta_save( $post_id ) {

    // Checks save status
    $is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id );
    $is_revision = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );
    $is_valid_nonce = ( isset( $_POST[ 'product_nonce' ] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ 'product_nonce' ], basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) ? 'true' : 'false';

    // Exits script depending on save status
    if ( $is_autosave || $is_revision || !$is_valid_nonce ) {
        return;
    }

    // Checks for input and sanitizes/saves if needed
    if( isset( $_POST[ 'meta_desc' ] ) ) {

        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta_desc', sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'meta_desc' ] ) );

    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'product_meta_save');
```

And thats how I tried to get my value:

```
    $desc = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'meta_desc', true );
echo $desc;
```

But it didn't worked, I hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing your code there are a couple of things you need to change depending on where the meta content is being held.

Try this to get the value

```
$desc = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'meta_desc', TRUE );
echo  $desc;
```

That Will be give you the appropriate meta.

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't help. still getting an empty value... where's the best place to echo my $desc? Or are there any other methods?

Comment: @HannesD. You can echo it into the while loop where you are displaying your products

Comment: I've figured it out! I was always in my index-loop and requested a post-id from the real posts and not from the product-posts. So I created a new post type and made a new loop and put your written code in it. Now everything works.